# Compile older version of gcc

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction, gmp, mpfr

I am trying to compile gcc version gcc4.3.2 using  gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-50) on a CentOS 5.5 os. Initially the compiler complained about needing gmp and mpfr libraries which were then downloaded, compiled and installed successfully.

After the installation, the new configure command that was used was:

../gcc4.3.2/gcc-4.3.2/configure --prefix=/home/shahw/gccdir/ --with-gmp=/usr/local/ --with-mpfr=/usr/local/

I now encounter the following error:

```
checking for x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-strip... strip
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking for x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc... /home/shahw/gccobj/./gcc/xgcc -
B/home/shahw/gccobj/./gcc/ -B/home/shahw/gccdir//x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/               
B/home/shahw/gccdir//x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/ -isystem /home/shahw/gccdir//x86_64-    
unknown-linux-gnu/include -isystem /home/shahw/gccdir//x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/sys-include
checking for suffix of object files... configure: error: cannot compute suffix of object files: cannot compile
See `config.log' for more details.
make[2]: *** [configure-stage1-target-libgcc] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/shahw/gccobj'
make[1]: *** [stage1-bubble] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/shahw/gccobj'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

config.log contains the following at the end:

```
## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
#define PACKAGE_NAME ""
#define PACKAGE_STRING ""
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
#define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
#endif
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" void std::exit (int) throw (); using std::exit;

configure: exit 0
```

Any hint towards a potential solution would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a link that seems good to start with:
http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-from-scratch-13/why-cannot-compute-suffix-of-object-files-350753/

Comment: I recompiled mpfr with the --with-gmp=/usr/local option. Another change that I made was to set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH to /usr/local/lib instead of just /usr/local. That did the trick. Thanks!